# Disable Checkbox for Parent rows in Lightning Tree Grid

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using Lightning:TreeGrid to show some tabular data which of Hierarchial structure. I want the Checkbox only to be visible for Children and not parents rows in the hierarchy. Is there a way we can do this?

Comment: would to like to share your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I am also looking for same requirement is it achievable ?